# Applescript service code to get value of a selected cell

Tags: numbers, applescript

I state that I am not a programmer and I have no experience with applescript. I have a "Numbers" file with some data in the "A" column. I want to select a value by clicking on it and thought I would run an applescript service to assign the selected value to a global variable and write the value stored in another cell in the sheet.
I found a similar script that seems to work in fact the value is stored in the variable but later the automator tells me that it cannot set the value read to the cell where I would like it to be compiled.

```
enter code here
```

on run {input, parameters}
global mybox
set mybox to 0

```
tell application "Numbers"
    tell the front document to ¬
        tell the active sheet to ¬
            set CurrentTable to the first table whose class of selection range is range
    tell the CurrentTable to get the value of the first cell in the selection range
    
    if the result is not missing value then set mybox to result
    display dialog "Cell value: " & mybox
    set the value of cell "b2" to mybox
    
    
end tell

return input
```

end run

Comment: @Robert - You are right and I wanted to apologize for not having been able to argue my request from the beginning. I will try to post more details

Answer (score 0):

And, no need some service to get value of selected cell in Numbers.app. Example:

```
tell application "Numbers" to tell document 1 to tell active sheet to ¬
    tell table 1 to set globalVariable to formatted value of ¬
        item 1 of (cells of (get selection range))
```

NOTE. You can embed this script in the automator service, but it will make things slower, and doesn't make sense.